# Vertical cell padding

Tags: mediawiki

I can apply cell padding to a single cell like this:

```
{| style="text-align: center;"
|-
| style="padding: 20px 100px 20px 50px"|test  || test2
|}
```

Is there any way to apply the padding to the entire row? Or all cells in the table?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add HTML attributes to every table cell (except repeating them manually). You can use standard CSS mechanisms to apply styles to every cell (add a class to the table, add a CSS rule for `table.someclass td`), but you need to modify the global CSS or use inline `<style>` tags (which is a big security risk if configured carelessly).

Comment: I tried to use inline style tags like this:
http://www.itk.org/Wiki/ITK/Getting_Started/Obtain

but they seems to just show up as text. Do I need this extension to do this: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StyleTags ?

Comment: There are a bunch of extensions, plus the [$wgRawHtml](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgRawHtml) setting. Once again, this is dangerous stuff, XSS attacks can be embedded in a style sheet, so make sure you choose a solution where no one you do not trust is able to add style rules.

Comment: I do not have access to the server, so I can't install any extensions or change any variables. Is there no other way to pad cells without copying that giant 'padding:' line in front of every single cell?

Comment: If you have right to edit the `MediaWiki` namespace, you can define global CSS rules.

Comment: You mean this page: http://www.itk.org/Wiki/MediaWiki ? I seem to be able to create a page there...

Comment: [itk.org/Wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/MediaWiki:Common.css).